# Apple Developer Enterprise Program app has no icon

Tags: ios

I can't download my app which using the Apple Developer Enterprise Program to created and distributed

Error occurs when I download app using the .ipa file's URL, the downloaded app does not have an icon.

[image: app has no icon]

Comment: It's still downloading. Wait a few minutes. Downloaded app should not be greyed out.

Comment: Have you set the `display-image` and `url` in your ipa manifest file configuration?

Comment: @Itachi In my .plist file, there only a url of .ipa file

Comment: @Raptor Just added the app icon on the desktop, but did not download it

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the `display-image` and `url` value in your mainfest.plist configure file, this url icon will show in the desktop when downloading the app.

```
   <dict>
         <key>kind</key>
         <string>display-image</string>
         <key>needs-shine</key>
         <true/>
         <key>url</key>
         <string>http://www.example.com/image.57x57.png</string>
   </dict>
```

Use the https scheme for the icon url if necessary.

See more key details in [this link](https://github.com/nifcblm/AHPP-iOS-App/wiki/How-to-distribute-enterprise-iOS-App).